# COM interface always masking exception message with "catastrophic failure"

Tags: delphi, exception, activex, message

I have a Delphi ActiveX project with 4 interfaces. Two of them have AutoComObject factories for their CoClasses. All the methods of the interfaces are declared with safecalls. In the interfaces with the factories, if a exception is thrown in any method,  the caller receives an EOleException with the exception message from the original exception in the activex. But in the other two interfaces any exception gets masked as EOleException with the message masked to "Catastrophic Failure".

Anyone knows why this is happening, and how to make the original exception message not get masked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If an unhandled exception escapes a `safecall` method of a class, [`TObject.SafeCallException()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.TObject.SafeCallException) is called to convert the exception into an `HRESULT` error code, which is then returned by COM to the caller.  By default, `TObject.SafeCallException()` always returns `E_UNEXPECTED` (`$8000FFFF`).  A class can override `SafeCallException()` to return a more meaningful `HRESULT`.  `TComObject` and `TAutoIntfObject` do exactly that, for instance (they also call [`SetErrorInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221409(v=vs.85).aspx) to set detailed information about the exception, which the caller can retrieve using [`GetErrorInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032(v=vs.85).aspx) if desired).  So it sounds like your two `AutoComObject`-based objects have a `SafeCallException()` implementation, and your other two objects do not.

Comment: thanks, your answer was helpful. Creating an autoobject factory for those two classes and declaring them to extend from TAutoObject, which in turn extends from TComObject, solved the problem.